# An error occurs configuring project:app in developing android app using gradle build tools

Tags: android, build.gradle

I am new to android development and I 'm building android app. I'm using gradle and I got the error message `A problem occurred configuring project ':app'`.

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
        //classpath 'ext.supportLibraryVersion = 27.1.1'

        classpath 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

The above code is the project level of build.gradle file.
The following code is the app level of build.gradle file.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "mm.com.fairway.firebaseauth"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'



    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'


}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I searched the solution to fix this error and I don't find the solution yet. Any ideas for this error and Thank you.

Comment: classpath 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1' is possible the reason why. you have it in the wrong Gradle file.

Answer (score 0):

```
classpath 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1
```

The above line is in the wrong Gradle file. Also change it from classpath to implementation.

So something like this:

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.2'
        //classpath 'ext.supportLibraryVersion = 27.1.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "mm.com.fairway.firebaseauth"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'


    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'


}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Do note, I updated the project to 28 and other dependencies were also upgraded. I did this as I don't have SDK 27 installed anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading your Gradle build tools to 3.2 or higher will solve this problem.

For example:

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'
        //classpath 'ext.supportLibraryVersion = 27.1.1'

        classpath 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

This solved it for me and seems to have solved it for this other person as well:

[I have a gradle sync error JAVA_LETTER_OR_DIGIT when trying to add Firebase to my android project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58102484/i-have-a-gradle-sync-error-java-letter-or-digit-when-trying-to-add-firebase-to-m)